# Initialize a struct with a const char * names[] inside

Tags: gcc, struct, constants

I saw a lot of questions about this, but I am making a question because, this is far from what I seen in other questions...I think the sctruct is well initialized...well at least teorically...

GdkColor is a struct in GTK with 4 int numbers inside so { 0, 65535, 0, 0} to initialize it...

I am using gcc compiler.

So I have this struct:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct components{
    GtkWidget *window;
        GtkWidget *table;
            GtkWidget *table_box;
                GtkWidget *describe;
                    GdkColor color;
                    const gchar *gcolor;
                GtkWidget *combo_bboard;
                GtkWidget *combo_bmcu;
                GtkWidget *go;
               GtkWidget *plugin_notebook;
                const gchar *notebook_name_pages[5];
                    gint num_pages;
                    GtkWidget *name_page;
                    GtkWidget *frame;
                    GtkWidget *content;
                        GtkWidget *checkbutton;
}plugin_items;

/* plugin_items items; */
plugin_items items = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, { 0, 65535, 0, 0 }, 
               {"red"}, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, { "Features", "Diagram", 
               "Peripherals", "Registers", "ASM Instructions" }, 0, NULL, 
               NULL, NULL, NULL };

   /* THIS Is THE 32 LINE that gcc complains about */
   items.num_pages = (gint)( (sizeof( items.notebook_name_pages)/sizeof( void *));
```

when I compile I got a weird error :

```
gcc -c  environment.c -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` 
environment.c:32:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
make: *** [environment.o] Error 1
```

I am tired, but I think all is ok...

why? HELP ME GOD....

Does any body knows how to solve this?
I don't know what is the error...I am using GTK.
I can't solve this, I don't  understand the error :S, and I can't find it...
I stay in a DEAD END for about two days...

I appreciate your help please guys.
Maybe I am doing something that is completely stupid...but I don't  know where :S

thanks in advance
jonh

Comment: Errors on lines 57-59 but only 26 lines are showing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I Have updated the question, sorry for that :S suddenly the problem appears in line 32 where I am telling items.num_pages that the number of pages are 5...but I don't  know why, it complains about :S Thanks for the help

Comment: I see 5 left parentheses in that line and only 4 right parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions the C-Language does not allow code outside functions, so this code has to go in a function.  You have to do something like:

```
void myfunction(){
    items.num_pages = ...
}
```